# turn on/off an external usb ssd with UHUBCTL

Tags: debian, usb, block-device, proxmox

I need to turn on/off an external usb ssd on my Proxmox VE 8 zimaboard832 (Debian 12 Bookworm) automatically.
It's possibile with [uhubctl](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/uhubctl)? If it is, how can i make a turn_on/off bash script safely?

Answer (score 0):

`uhubctl` doesn't turn off devices.  It turns off the power to USB port the device is connected to.  This has the effect of disconnecting and reconnecting the external device ("port off" causes a disconnect, "port on" causes it to renegotiate and reconnect).

So `uhubctl` *may* be able to do what you want... if the USB port, itself, is able to be controlled.  Not all USB ports can be programmatically controlled in this way.

Now there's also `udiskctl` which can force a disk to disconnect.  And there's also the `eject` command.

So there’s two main ways of “removing” a USB device. And which option is used depends on what file manager is used!

The first is a “soft eject”. This is what the `eject` command does, and also appears to be what “pcmanfm” does. In this scenario, `eject -t` will cause the partitions to reappear. This works because the device is still connected to the bus (and still shows in /dev/) and so the OS can control it.  Depending on if your setup automounts devices or not, it may be safe to remove disks at this point.  The device still has power.

The other is more “hard”. This is what `udiskctl power-off` and Nautilus does. Here the device is effectively removed from the bus and so disappears from /dev/

e.g.

```
# /usr/bin/udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdg
# dmesg | tail -1
[179677.977567] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
```

We can see the kernel has reported the USB device has been disconnected. It no longer shows up in `lsusb` as a result.  It's safe to remove this device.

Finally we can try to control the USB port itself.

That “usb 1-2.2” becomes important. This means USB bus 1-2, port 2.

We can use `uhubctl` to re-enabled it, by turning it off and on:

```
# /usr/sbin/uhubctl -l 1-2 -p 2 -a off  
Current status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0101 power connect []
Sent power off request
New status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0000 off

# uhubctl -l 1-2 -p 2 -a on 
Current status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0000 off
Sent power on request
New status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0101 power connect []
```

And it’s re-appeared again!

```
[179834.775058] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[179834.888056] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567, bcdDevice= 1.00
[179834.888063] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[179834.888067] usb 1-2.2: Product: Cruzer Blade
[179834.888070] usb 1-2.2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[179834.888074] usb 1-2.2: SerialNumber: 4C530000260115213093
```

Note that not all hubs can be controlled this way.

For hubs that do have "power control" `uhubctl` is a great way of powering down remote devices.

Comment: Many thanks. I've written to zimaboard support team to understand if usb has power control and then I'll try this.